# Sending 2 different messages if message exceeds 2000 characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically I'm making this lyrics command, and many times, the amount of characters in a lyric for most songs exceed 2000 characters, which is passed Discord's limit. I wonder how I would go about making it send 2 different messages at once.

I'm wondering how I could make it send the first 2000 characters in one message, then send the remaining characters in a second message right after.

Here is my code right here:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + `lyrics`)) {
        var artistTitle = getArtistTitle(serverQueue.songs[0].title)

        console.log(artistTitle)
        lyrics.get(artistTitle[0], artistTitle[1], function(err, res){
            if(err){
                return message.channel.send({embed: {
                    title: `:x:  ｜   Oops! I have encountered an error!`,
                    description: err,
                    color: 0xDE2E43
                }})
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                return message.channel.send({embed: {
                    title: `Lyrics for ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}. Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
                    description: res,
                    footer: {
                        icon_url: serverQueue.songs[0].thumbnail,
                        text: `Powered by lyrics.wikia.com`
                    }
                }})
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Here is my code right now https://pastebin.com/j6bbF4TB

Comment: Please add your relevant code to the question, not just in a pastebin link

Comment: From the code on your pastebin, it looks like you want to send all of the lyric text as an `embed`?

Comment: yeah i want to like send 2 different embeds when character count exceeds 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring to cut the message up:

```
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2000) {
    const toSend = str.substring(i, Math.min(str.length, i + 2000));
    sendMessage(toSend);
}
```

Comment: ty i will try this

Comment: @FreezIn if I helped, please make sure to mark my answer as correct :)